# 3rd Gen Macbook pro randomly suspends

Tags: macbook-pro

My 3rd Gen (late 2013) MBP randomly suspends.

I've already seen [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/14844/macbook-pro-randomly-restarting) and [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/304624/macbook-pro-retina-15-early-2013-randomly-shuts-down) and [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/14844/macbook-pro-randomly-restarting) and [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/333632/late-2013-macbook-pro-turns-off-at-random-times). And unfortunately, none of them quite match what's happening to me.

I will be in the middle of working on my MBP and it will randomly suspend so I have to hit the power button to wake. Pressing the power button resumes from suspend but then it will do it again within a few seconds of use unless I plug it in. Does not seem to necessarily be tied to the remaining battery life (happens more often < 40% but it's happened at 68% and I've gotten down to 5% as recently as this week without seeing the problem).

This is a core i7 machine with 16 GB RAM and a 500 GB SSD. Coconut battery reports that I still have 75%+ of the original battery capacity left. This is a machine that otherwise has plenty of life left in it if I can get this resolved.

Any ideas what could be wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Your battery is dying.  It's time to replace it.

You have very similar symptoms to the issue in this other post [Fully charged MacBook Air turns off when power cord removed](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/254180/119271), but the major difference is that you have enough "juice" to allow macOS to suspend rather than just turn off all at once.

One of the [biggest factors in batteries dying is it's age](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/238125/119271).  This is a 2013 MacBook Pro, so it's got 6 years on it.  The average lifepan of a battery is 3 to 5 years so (some last only 2 while some go 6 or 7), you're outside it's usable life.

#### Battery utilities

Coconut Battery, et. al. are neat little tools, however, they can only give a point-in-time *calculation* of your battery's heath.  It does it by measuring the current (volts and amps) and the current draw.  What it *can't* do is measure the charge like a fuel gauge in your car.

This is why you're seeing the (confusing and conflicting) "battery's ok but system sleeps when not plugged in" symptom.

Comment: I was afraid of that. Is it even replaceable in a late 2013 MBP?

Comment: Yes.  It's most definitely replaceable.  See the "biggest factors" link for further info.

Comment: Replaced it no problem, in addition to the excellent link you gave I found [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tY63Cs9OA1Q) very helpful if anyone else is performing the same repair.